# Using inheritance in MSTest

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I am setting up some MSTest based unit tests.  To make my life easier I want to use a base class that handles the generic setup and taredown all of my tests require.  My base class looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class DBTestBase {
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext) {
        var config = new XmlConfigurationSource("ARconfig_test.xml");
        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(Assembly.Load("LocalModels"), config);
    }

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize() {
        ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchema();
        Before_each_test();
    }

    protected virtual void Before_each_test() { }

    [TestCleanup()]
    public void MyTestCleanup() {
        After_each_test();
    }

    protected virtual void After_each_test() { }
}
```

My actual test class looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class question_tests : DBTestBase {

    private void CreateInitialData() {
        var question = new Question()
                           {
                               Name = "Test Question",
                               Description = "This is a simple test question"
                           };
        question.Create();
    }

    protected override void Before_each_test() {
        base.Before_each_test();
        CreateInitialData();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void test_fetching() {
        var q = Question.FindAll();
        Assert.AreEqual("Test Question", q[0].Name, "Incorrect name.");
    }
}
```

The TestInitialize function works as expected.  But the ClassInitialize function never runs.  It does run if I add the following to my child class:

```
    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void t(TestContext testContext) {
        MyClassInitialize(testContext);
    }
```

Is it possible to get my base class initialize function to run without referencing it in my child class?

Comment: Too hacky to add as an answer: try using a static constructor in the base class.

Comment: I ended up using AssemblyInitialize().  Not exactly what I wanted, but I guess MSTest doesn't do it.

@Roufamatic, your answer is probobly the only way.  If you post it, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirm this was a problem for me too.  I used a constructor on the base and a destructor for the cleanup

Comment: The problem with that is that the finalizer isn't guaranteed to run at a deterministic time.  For example in my tests I want to impersonate a given user, but once my tests are done undo the impersonation.  That won't work with a finalizer, because most likely a number of my other tests will run before it is run.

Comment: The problem with the constructor is that it works the same as TestInitialize. It will run on every test.

Comment: There is no Finalizer here - only the use of TestCleanup() - BIG difference.  The behavior and execution of TestCleanup() is deterministic and well-defined.

Answer (score 8):

ClassInitialize method is executed if and only if the concerned "class" contains at least one TestMethod, and at least one TestMethod from the class is selected for execution.

Comment: Well, that is a pretty dumb way to code it.  TestInitialize and TestCleanup don't work that way...

Comment: agreed - but thats the way it is :-(

Comment: I added this to my code:
    [ClassInitialize]  
    public new static void ClassSetup(TestContext context)  
    {  
       TestBase.ClassSetup(context);  
    }

Answer (score -1):

```
[TestClass]
public class question_tests : DBTestBase {
...
    [TestCleanup()]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        base.MyTestCleanup();
    }
```